# Android app crashing when toast is run in try catch

Tags: java, android, try-catch, android-toast

I'm creating an android app that has a login screen. What I did was that whenever the user clicks the submit button, it runs a progressdialog. then call a new thread to verify the login. When I try to run a toast on the function inside the login, the app suddenly crashes. What I did with it is this:

```
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
               dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", 
                        "Validating user...", true);
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){


                    login();
                }
            }).start();
        }

    });
```

then my login function is this:

```
void login(){

try{
//some code
} catch(Exception e){

dialog.dismiss();
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();

}
```

But for some reason once it goes to the catch function the app suddenly crashes **only when I add the code for the toast**. What is wrong with my code and why is it crashing only when I am using toasts?

Comment: have you looked at the LogCat of the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toast is in another work thread ?

Can you put the toast in runOnUiThread() ?

Comment: I just transferred the entire toast on the runOnUiThread(). Why is this so? is it because I placed the toast inside a new thread that I used to run the login function?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging your code? You probably get null pointer from getApplicationContext() as you are calling it from your thread. Declare a variable context somewhere and use that variable to make Toast(if you need it).